# Detect the Browser and show a other content

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I build a website only with CSS3 & HTML5.
So IE can't display it correct.
I want to show every Internet Explorer-User a other site with a simple content: Please use a modern browser like Google Chrome, Fire Fox ...

How can i detect the browser and show a other site? 
Or can i build a text for the Internet Explorer users like

```
<div style="display:none;">Please use a modern Browser!</div>
```

and let show it only for Internet Explorer-Users?

Comment: IE supports a reasonable subset of CSS 3 and HTML 5.

Comment: Did you search the interwebs for detecting IE? Better yet is to sniff for support of the things you use. Look at http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Most people who see such a message will be either unable or unwilling to change anyway.

Comment: Content is king. The presentation might degrade, but it should do so [gracefully](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement). That isn't a reason to kick people off the site.

Comment: the most of the "normal" user surf with IE, cause it is installed on Windows. 
But IE is devil! we must the people attention to it!
so, when they want to see my site, they must change the browser...

Comment: IE is not the devil. It is a decent browser these days.

Comment: It may be a bit optimistic to expect users to switch browsers just to access a single website.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize IE detects that IE itself puts out. So place the div with the display none, and then make an ie stylesheet and target all the different versions you would like.

More information on specifics here: http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: Glad to help! If you don't mind selecting it as your official answer (if it turns out well for you!), I'd really appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

there is better option instead of adding a new style sheet

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie6" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]> <html class="ie ie7" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]> <html class="ie ie8" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9 ]> <html class="ie ie9" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 9]><!-->
<html lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->
```

and in style sheet just add a class for selector

```
.page {
    //some style for morden browsers
}
.ie .page {
    //some style for all ie versions
}
.ie6 .page {
    //some style for ie 6 only
}
.ie7 .page {
    //some style for ie 7 only
}
.ie8 .page {
    //some style for ie 8 only
}
.ie9 .page {
    //some style for ie 9 only
}
```

it would be done using a single style sheet

Answer (score 0):

`navigator.userAgent`

there is a very cool script here: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/detect.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following :

```
<?php
$u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i', $u_agent)) 
{ 
    // Change http://www.othersite.com, by your other site URL
    header('Location: http://www.othersite.com'); 
} 
?>
```

You can also use conditional comments for IE.

Comment: where is the [tag:php] tag? :)